# Drawing a fiber bundle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Fiber bundles are ubiquitous creatures in mathematics which are appealing in a bunch of ways. In many of my notes I would like to include pictures and diagrams of fiber bundles. Online I have found the following wonderful picture:

[image]

How does one typeset such a diagram (in `Tikz` I'm guessing)? I don't even know where to start.
The only diagrams I know how to draw are commutative diagrams in `xy-pic`.

Comment: Why not just include the image with `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @cfr I want to see how such diagrams are made so I can learn to make small changes myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here an approach

**Code**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\tiny}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw(2,0)--(4,0)node[midway,below]{fibre bundle}arc(0:70:4)--(90:2)arc(90:0:2)--cycle;

\draw[->] (20:1.3)node[below,xshift=-2mm]{base manifold}--(30:2);

\begin{scope}[bend right]
\foreach \i[count=\x] in {10,30,50,70}
{\node(a\x)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]at (\i:2.4){};
\draw(a\x)to(a\x|-0,4);}

\foreach \i[count=\x] in {7,26,46,66}
{\node(b\x)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]at (\i:3){};
\draw(b\x)to(b\x|-0,4);}

\foreach \i[count=\x] in {6,26,46,66}
{\node(c\x)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]at (\i:3.6){};
\draw(c\x)to(c\x|-0,4);}

\path(c1)to coordinate[near start](d)(c1|-0,4);
\end{scope}
\draw[<-](d)--+(0.8,-0.5)node[right]{fibre};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]