# Typesetting category of elements diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

[This nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+elements#idea) features the two diagrams below which I would like to typeset myself, except I only know `xypic` which cannot really produce them.

[image]

[image]

I would like to typeset the following:

[image]

What is a short and easy way to produce this?

**Added.** Just so it's clear - it's no problem to produce the left and middle diagrams with `xypic`, the problem for me is the right one, and I'd like everything to be typeset together, so I'm asking for all three of them (I guess most people will use `tikz`).

**Added later.** Here's the code for the two left diagrams with `xypic`:

`\xymatrix{X\ar@/^{0.5pc}/@[blue][rr]^{f}\ar@/_{0.5pc}/@[green][rr]_{g} &  & Y} \qquad\longrightarrow\qquad\vcenter{\xymatrix{x_{2}\ar@/^{1pc}/@[green][rr]\ar@/_{0.5pc}/@[blue][ddrr] &  & y_{2}\\ x_{1}\ar@/^{0.5pc}/@[blue][rr]\ar@/_{0.5pc}/@[green][rr] &  & y_{1}\\ x_{3}\ar@/_{1pc}/@[green][rr]\ar@/^{0.5pc}/@[blue][uurr] &  & y_{3} } }`

Comment: Well, what have you got so far? The introductory tutorials are pretty good and you should not have too much difficulty with the first 2 diagrams or the arrows. If you get stuck, post the code you've got. 'I'm asking for all three of them' is not how the site is supposed to work. That is to say, somebody may do everything for you, but I think they shouldn't and I don't think it reasonable to ask. (I note that I might even do all three for you. But I think I ought not so I'm not planning on it.)

Comment: [6 months ago](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289165/drawing-a-fiber-bundle#comment699915_289165) you said you wanted to avoid `\includegraphics` when asking a do-it-for-me question because you wanted to learn how diagrams were created. I guess we haven't helped you much if you're asking another. That's a shame.

Comment: @cfr I added what I made so far with `xypic`. The answer to the question you link was great, but I haven't had the chance to work through it and learn how to make my own. I very rarely use any graphic packages other than `xypic`.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. But if you really want to learn TikZ, as you indicated before, then probably you have to start using it when you could use `xypic`. Otherwise, if you only use it when you need something more powerful, you'll always be faced with a complicated thing to draw rather than being able to start simple. Why don't you see if you can translate the first 2 pictures into TikZ?

Comment: I advice you (again) to abandon the idea of using xy. Tikz is the most powerful and flexible environment where your problem can be addressed. Consider seriously learning it!

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I will learn it eventually! For now I'm using LyX, and `xypic` is integrated in it.