# Drawing fiber bundle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a fibre bundle with tikz in cylindrical form, for now I am only able to do something like this:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw(2,0)--(4,0)node[midway,below]{fibre bundle}arc(0:70:4)--(90:2)arc(90:0:2)--cycle;

\draw[->] (20:1.3)node[below,xshift=-2mm]{base manifold}--(30:2);

\begin{scope}[bend right]
\foreach \i[count=\x] in {10,30,50,70}
{\node(a\x)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]at (\i:2.4){};
\draw(a\x)to(a\x|-0,4);}

\foreach \i[count=\x] in {7,26,46,66}
{\node(b\x)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]at (\i:3){};
\draw(b\x)to(b\x|-0,4);}

\foreach \i[count=\x] in {6,26,46,66}
{\node(c\x)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]at (\i:3.6){};
\draw(c\x)to(c\x|-0,4);}

\path(c1)to coordinate[near start](d)(c1|-0,4);
\end{scope}
\draw[<-](d)--+(0.8,-0.5)node[right]{fibre};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to have a general circle in the bottom (in perspective) then the fibre coming up forming a cylinder (3-dimensional in perspective). Something like this:
[image]

Or this: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trivialization.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thank you for including code. How exactly do you want it to look? You haven't included an example image or description of it, I just compiled your code now so can see it

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/289165

Comment: You're not actually using `tikz-cd`. Just `tikz`.

Comment: I want to have a general circle in the bottom then the fibre coming up forming a cylinder

Comment: @Lucien Do you mean this kind of fibre bundle https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trivialization.html ?

Comment: @Lucien You're question could be improved by adding a class, the necessary package and everything else necessary to actually compile the code fragment.

Comment: Yes I mean something like this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trivialization.html

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how the fibers could form a cylinder but maybe this way?

The second diagram was made without any consideration of three dimensionalness, the *z* and *y* dimensions are the same.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.5cm]
\draw circle[radius=3];
\foreach[count=\i from 0] \angle in {0, 30, ..., 359}
  \foreach[count=\j from 0] \radius in {1, 1.5, 2, 2.5}
    \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt] (n-\i-\j) at (\angle:\radius) {}[
      draw,
      x=(\angle+90:1cm+\j*.2cm),
      y=(90:1cm)
    ] (n-\i-\j) arc[start angle=-45, end angle=45, radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.5cm]
\foreach \dot in {1, ..., 13}
  \draw coordinate (n-\dot) at ([xslant=.3333] xyz cs: x={mod(\dot,5)}, y={int(\dot/5)})
    (n-\dot) -- (n-\dot|-0,-4);
\draw[fill=white] (n-7) circle[radius=2.4];
\foreach \dot in {1, ..., 13}
  \draw node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt] (n-\dot) at (n-\dot) {}
  (n-\dot) -- (n-\dot|-0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: I edited the question with an image of what i thought, thank you

Comment: @Lucien See my update.

Comment: Thank you so much!